# Conditional statement in QtiPlot

Tags: python, plot

I tried to fill column with some values using conditional expression "if":

```
if(col("6")-0.02)<0; 0; col("6")-0.02)
```

Hint fot "if" function in QtiPlot:

> ```
> if(e1; e2; e3):
> if e1 then e2 else e3.
> ```

QtiPlot returns error:

> Unexpected token "if" found at position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if-statement` is removed from the `muParser` in favor of a ternary operator, like in C/C++. So `if(e1, e2, e3)` is replaced with `(e1) ? e2:e3`.